# How can I make this repetitive column data into proper data?

Tags: r, reshape, data-transform

How do I change this table from wide to long format in R? I have tried a few different libraries but can't seem to get it.

```
  Region  A  B  C Region  A  B  C Region  A  B  C
1     SS 45 98 89     KK 87 NA 25     MM 88 NA 59
2     SS 22 NA 77     KK 45 78 88     MM NA 72 35
```

I have tried using `reshape(df5, idvar=" " , timevar='' , direction="")` but can't fix my data.

I want this data as-

```
  Region  A  B  C
1     SS 45 98 89
2     SS 22 NA 77
3     KK 87 NA 25
4     KK 45 78 88
5     MM 88 NA 59
6     MM NA 72 35
```

It would be great if I get the answer using `reshape`.

Comment: Please use `dput` to present your data.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually a `reshape` problem. What you want is to `rbind` every n + 1 columns, where `n` is the `length` of the repeating names.

```
n <- length(s <- grep('Region', names(dat)))

do.call(rbind, Map(\(x, y) dat[x + (n + 1)*y], list(1:(s[2] - 1)), 0:(n - 1)))
#   Region  A  B  C
# 1     SS 45 98 89
# 2     SS 22 NA 77
# 3     KK 87 NA 25
# 4     KK 45 78 88
# 5     MM 88 NA 59
# 6     MM NA 72 35
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Region = c("SS", "SS"), A = c(45L, 22L), B = c(98L, 
NA), C = c(89L, 77L), Region = c("KK", "KK"), A = c(87L, 45L), 
    B = c(NA, 78L), C = c(25L, 88L), Region = c("MM", "MM"), 
    A = c(88L, NA), B = c(NA, 72L), C = c(59L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Actually, I have the repetition of "Region, A,B,C" like 50 times in the whole dataset. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: @SubhojitChakraborty You don't seem willing to count the number of repetitions-I wouldn't be either :) Please see update for non-hardcoded version.

Answer (score 0):

Another base `R` option like this:

```r
df5 <- read.table(text = "  Region  A  B  C Region  A  B  C Region  A  B  C
1     SS 45 98 89     KK 87 NA 25     MM 88 NA 59
2     SS 22 NA 77     KK 45 78 88     MM NA 72 35", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

as.data.frame(lapply(split(lapply(df5, as.character), names(df5)), unlist))
#>      A    B  C Region
#> 1   45   98 89     SS
#> 2   22 <NA> 77     SS
#> 3   87 <NA> 25     KK
#> 4   45   78 88     KK
#> 5   88 <NA> 59     MM
#> 6 <NA>   72 35     MM
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>